# Uploading image from React with antd to DRF

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, antd

I'm trying to upload a form inclusive of an Image to my DRF API from a react frontend using antd. On submitting the form I encounter the following error from DRF

```
{
  "photo": [
    "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."
  ]
}
```

This is the value received under "photo" when I check the values being submitted

```
"photo":[{"uid":"rc-upload-1647817573720-2","lastModified":1643547530011,"lastModifiedDate":"2022-01-30T12:58:50.011Z","name":"chibi spiderman.jpg","size":445488,"type":"image/jpeg","percent":0,"originFileObj":{"uid":"rc-upload-1647817573720-2"},"error":{"status":404,"method":"post","url":""},"response":"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot POST /app/new-individual</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n","status":"error"}]
```

My API is set up well and I believe the issue is mainly revolving around my handling of the form data before submitting to properly cater for the Image upload. But incase you need t view my code for the API just let me know. Here's a look at my frontend code

My Form item for the image within the form

```
<Form.Item
  name="photo"
  label = "Your Photo"
  valuePropName="fileList"
  getValueFromEvent={normFile}
>
  <Upload name='photo'>
    <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Click to Upload</Button>
  </Upload>
</Form.Item>
```

Function handling submit for the form

```
const onFinish = values => {
    values["date_of_birth"] = moment(values.date_of_birth).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
    if(values["dependants"] !== undefined){
        values["dependants"].forEach(d => {
            d["date_of_birth"] = moment(d.date_of_birth).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
        });
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(values))
    const userToken = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN)
    IndividualService.setToken(userToken)

    IndividualService.postIndividual(values).then(resp => {
        console.log(resp.individual_details)
        setIndividual(resp.individual_details)
        form.resetFields()
        localStorage.setItem("individualPlan", resp.individual_details.id)
        setSubmitted(true)
        message.success('successfully added details for Individual plan')

    }).catch(error => {
        message.error('Error occured, plase try again', error.message)
      })
    
  };
```

Comment: have you resolved this issue? If yes can you please post the solution?

Comment: @MahendraGarg no I haven't